# Convert php string data to Json object using Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I need to get some Json data from PHP to jquery.

I need the below format in a javascript method.

```
function returnJson()
{
   return {
            events: [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "start": new Date(2013, 4, 26, 12),
                "end": new Date(2013, 4, 26, 13, 30),
                "title": "Lunch with Mike"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "start": new Date(2013, 4, 27, 14),
                "end": new Date(2013,4, 27, 14, 45),
                "title": "Dev Meeting"
            }]
       };
}
```

For this I am doing the below things in javascript:

```
function returnJson()
{
    var eventResult = $.getJSON("../PHP/PhpAction.php?f=fetchCalendarEvent");
    return eventResult;
}
```

in php:

```
 function fetchCalendarEvent()
          {
              $tablename = "tb_calendar";

              $sql = "SELECT eventId,userId,enentName,eventText,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startTime) AS startyear,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM startTime) AS startMonth,EXTRACT(DAY FROM startTime) AS startDay,EXTRACT(HOUR FROM startTime) AS startHour,EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM startTime) AS startMin,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM endTime) AS endyear,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM endTime) AS endMonth,EXTRACT(DAY FROM endTime) AS endDay,EXTRACT(HOUR FROM endTime) AS e`enter code here`ndHour,EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM endTime) AS endMin FROM ".$tablename." WHERE userId='".$_SESSION['userid']."' AND isActive=1";

                        $q = mysql_query($sql);
                        $i=1;           
                        $eventData="{events: [";

                        if (!mysql_num_rows($q)) {
                            echo 'No records found';
                        }
                        else
                        {                                           
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {

                                $eventData.="{'id':".$row['eventId'].",";


                                $eventData.="'end': new Date(".$row['startyear'].",".$row['startMonth'].",".$row['startDay']."," .$row['startHour'].",".$row['startMin']."),";

                                $eventData.="'start': new Date(".$row['endyear'].",".$row['endMonth'].",".$row['endDay'].",".$row['endHour'].",".$row['endMin']."),";

                                $eventData.="'title':'".$row['enentName']."'},";

                                $i++;
                            }                   
                        }   
                        $eventData= rtrim($eventData, ",");

                        $eventData.="]}";
                        echo json_decode($eventData);
          }
```

I check in firebug the php method is returning data like:

```
{ events: [ {
        'id': 2,
        'end': new Date(2013, 4, 27, 18, 38),
        'start': new Date(2013, 4, 27, 18, 38),
        'title': 'test'
    }, {
        'id': 3,
        'end': new Date(2013, 4, 23, 11, 0),
        'start': new Date(2013, 4, 23, 14, 15),
        'title': 'testing23'
    }
] }
```

Can any one please help me. I am new in php. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably your web server does return the wrong html headers for JSON. Maybe you should use `jQuery.ajax()` - it has more options to "tweak"...

Comment: Store the data in an associative array and run json_encode() on it.

Comment: Sorry it's also not working..I think some major problem is there in my code.

Comment: Your JSON formatted string is invalid, it does not conform [the spec](http://json.org): all strings should be contained within *double* quotes and there is no JSON representation of `Date` objects.

Comment: Yes I think you have wrong brackets: You want to send an array of objects... shouldn't it be something like `[{x:'...', y:'...}],[{x:'...', y:'...'}]` ?

Comment: @ Marcel Korpel can you please give me some idea how I convert sql data to Json object properly.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that there is no standard way to encode dates in JSON. There are 2 common approaches but few technologies understand both. Some use an iso standard (`2000-01-01T23:59:59` iirc) and another uses something like `/Date(2000,01,01,23,59,59)/`. It's a real pain but there you go. Perhaps the simplest option is to encode to a unix epoch (seconds since 1/1/1970) and transfer it as a long. If you know what you're expecting, it should be easy to handle at either end

Comment: @Basic: The ISO standard is from ECMAScript 5 onwards, so it is not handled properly by all browsers. OP: The way to go is indeed use seconds from the UNIX epoch and send them through [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to the client and convert them there using JavaScript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (remember that `Date` expects one value to be the number of *milliseconds* since the UNIX epoch).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I don't suppose you've got a link to the docs which mention it?

Comment: @Basic: It's in the [ECMAScript 5 spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.9.1.15) and it isn't present in [ECMAScript 3](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9.4.2). Have a look at Kangax' [ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/) to see which browsers support the new Date functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Php has a function called json_encode which will handle the generation of json output.

Here is an example:

```
$o = array();
$o['events'] = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $event = array();
    $event['id'] = $row['id'];
    $event['start'] = "new Date(".$row['startyear'].",".$row['startMonth'].",".$row['startDay']."," .$row['startHour'].",".$row['startMin'].")";
    $event['end'] = "new Date(".$row['endyear'].",".$row['endMonth'].",".$row['endDay'].",".$row['endHour'].",".$row['endMin'].")";
    $event['title'] = $row['title'];

    $o['events'][] = $event;
}

return json_encode($o);
```

And the javscript code could be like this:

```
function returnJson()
{
    var events = $.getJSON("../PHP/PhpAction.php?f=fetchCalendarEvent");

    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        event.start = eval(event.start);
        event.end = eval(event.end);

        events[i] = event;
    }

    return events;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.But in this case id and title is fine.But how it handle the start and end date? Because in that case I need new Date(2013, 4, 26, 12) and there is no start row.I have month,year,day,min,hour as saparate row.

Comment: Well if you send date with "new date()" format, it will be interpreted as text. So instead I would convert date to timestamp, then again at javascript side I would convert it to date like this: "var date = new Date(timestamp*1000);" Its multiplied by 1000 because JS works with miliseconds.

Comment: I have a javascript function which return data.
    The function is
    
        function getEventData() {
    
          return { events: [{ "id": 2, "start": new Date(2013, 4, 24, 12, 0), "end": new Date(2013, 4, 24, 11, 0), "title": "test"}] };
        
    }
    
    it's working fine when I write the function like above (with hardcore data)
    
    When I use some variable then it's not working ..
    


    In the Alert the same data is coming.If I just copy the alert data and paste in return it's working fine.

Comment: @amitghosh as I said the "new Date" is interpreted simply as a string.  However there is an "eval" function in Javascript. You can loop the events object and reassign the start and end variables using "eval" like this: event.start = eval(event.start);

Comment: can you please write where I write this eval.Please..Am I write this on Javascript after getting the string or in server side I append eval in the string?

Comment: @amitghosh I have changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the appropriate headers and MIME type when sending AJAX data to the browser:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Here is some sample code on how to use your data sent to the browser:

```
    function requestData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                events = json.events;

                useData(events);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('Status: ' + status +' Error: ' + error);
            }
        });
    }
```

What does the error message say in your case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't format date objects in json. An option is to use a timestamp and convert it during the parsing of the json.

If you check http://jsonlint.com/ you will see your json gives errors.

Your syntax is a Javascript Object notation not a json notation. Javascript can generate json by using [json.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function.

I just double checked and if you stringify your javascript object the following conversion will take place :

```
var date = new Date(2013, 4, 26, 12);
var string = JSON.stringify(date);
console.log(string);
//output = 2013-05-26T10:00:00.000Z
console.log(JSON.parse(string));
//will again output 2013-05-26T10:00:00.000Z
```

So you can convert date objects to string with JSON.stringify. But you can't format them back to a Date object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = preg_replace('@new Date\(([^\)]*)\)@', '"$1"', $data);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

Result:

> new Date(2008,3,30,0,31,26) => "2008,3,30,0,31,26"

Comment: Waste of time... OP is inactive for more than half year... `Last seen Apr 23 at 16:30`